# Can I use this?

Tags: logo, plagiarism

Is this logo okay to put on a t-shirt and sell? If not, what can I do so I can? Thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: if you can take this and put on a shirt, you can design a basic logo imho. try create a logo from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If you are asking if you can use it as a logo for a company or product—no. They are essentially identical.

If you are asking if you can put it on a t-shirt—you can do whatever you like. I see t-shirts with parodies of big brand's logos on a daily basis. But remember the company can still sue you. Wether they do and wether or not a court would decide you are infringing any copyright is another matter (and dependent on your location, the use of the logo and t-shirt, the industries involved, the strength of the original brand, the likeliness of genuine confusion and countless other factors).

---

*I am not a lawyer, this is not legal advice. If you want legal advice, talk to a lawyer.*

Comment: in UK law, Parody is an acceptable use of other peoples artwork.

Comment: Which explains why I see them daily and why it's "dependent on your location" :)